# Mock new PrintWriter(String fileName) using EasyMock

Tags: java, junit4, easymock

My code uses `PrintWriter` to write a content to file, like

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
try
{
    writer = new PrintWriter( fileName + "_version", "UTF-8" );
    writer.println( "writing File" );
}
catch( FileNotFoundException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to write a jUnit test using EasyMock only. How do I mock `new` object creation of `PrintWriter` in EasyMock?

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test the above code with EasyMock.

That call to `new PrintWriter()` inside that try/catch can't be mocked with EasyMock. End of story.

You will either need PowerMock(ito), or JMockit in order to be able to get control over the result of `new()`.

Alternatively (and preferred): you should change your hard-to-test production code to something that is easier to test, by using dependency injection for example. One simple approach would be *pass* a FileWrite object to such code.

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is: "What do you want to test?".

Testing and mocking require a tested class and dependencies.

Here there a no visible tested class. If the idea is that you want to test the method creating and using the `PrintWriter`, yes, other answers are right, you can't. You need PowerMock on top of EasyMock to mock the `new`.

However, depending on what you are doing, meaningful refactoring will easily solve the problem. So if you give us a more complete example, we will be able to give some more advice.